# Parsing latitude and longitude with perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I have a document here that looks like this:

---

```
FICN10 CWIS 211446
ICEBERG BULLETIN FOR THE EAST COAST WATERS ISSUED BY ENVIRONMENT
CANADA AT 11:00 A.M. EDT TUESDAY 21 OCTOBER 2014 FOR TODAY.
THE NEXT SCHEDULED BULLETIN WILL BE ISSUED AT 11:00 A.M. WEDNESDAY.
ICEBERG LIMIT AT 0000 UTC 22 OCT ESTIMATED FROM NEWFOUNDLAND NEAR
4900N 5350W TO 4830N 4900W TO 5000N 4900W TO 6000N 5830W TO
6000N 4000W TO 3000N 5000W.
```

---

I am trying to use a perl script in which I can get the coordinates into a csv file that looks like this:

```
4900N 5350W 
4830N 4900W
5000N 4900W
6000N 5830W
6000N 4000W
3000N 5000W
```

I have a snippet of code in which I was trying to do this put I do not get the intended results:

Can you look at the code and see what should be done in order to get all the coordinates from the text file into the above format?

Below is the code:

```
`rm -f coords.TXT`;
open FPOUT, ">$outfile" or die "\nERROR: Could create/write $outfile\n\n";
for ( $ii = 0; $ii < 7; $ii++ ) {
    #if ($ii==5)
    #{
    #   print STDOUT "LINE 1\n";
    #}
    #if ($ii==6)
    #{
    #   print STDOUT "LINE 2\n";
    #}
    @words = split " ", "$inline[$ii]";
    for ( $jj = 0; $jj < (@words); $jj++ ) {
        @char = split "", "$words[$jj]";
        $n = 0;
        for ( $kk = 0; $kk < (@char); $kk++ ) {
            $n = $n + 1;
        }
        if ( $n =~ 5 or $n =~ 6 ) {
            if ( $char[0] =~ /[a-zA-z]/ ) {

            } else {
                if ( $char[4] =~ "W" or $char[4] =~ "E" or $char[4] =~ "N" or $char[4] =~ "S" ) {
                    if ( $n =~ 6 ) {
                        if ( $char[5] =~ "." ) {
                            $words[$jj] =~ s/\.//;
                        }
                    }
                    if ( $char[4] =~ "W" or $char[4] =~ "E" ) {
                        $lon = $words[$jj];
                        print STDOUT "longitude is $lon\n";
                    } elsif ( $char[4] =~ "N" or $char[4] =~ "S" ) {
                        $lat = $words[$jj];
                        print STDOUT "Latitude is $lat\n";

                    }
                    print FPOUT "$lat $lon\n";
                }

            }
        }

    }
}

close FPOUT;
```

Comment: Just to offer a *possible* alternative approach, it looks like Environment Canada provides an [atom feed](http://weather.gc.ca/business/index_e.html#rss) for marine weather warnings, including ice warnings. If it gives the same data, it *might* be easier to parse as XML than as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

#### Parsing data with Regular Expressions

To pull out your desired pattern, you just need a regex:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    print "$_\n" for /\b\d+[NS]\s+\d+[WE]\b/g;
}

__DATA__
FICN10 CWIS 211446
ICEBERG BULLETIN FOR THE EAST COAST WATERS ISSUED BY ENVIRONMENT
CANADA AT 11:00 A.M. EDT TUESDAY 21 OCTOBER 2014 FOR TODAY.
THE NEXT SCHEDULED BULLETIN WILL BE ISSUED AT 11:00 A.M. WEDNESDAY.
ICEBERG LIMIT AT 0000 UTC 22 OCT ESTIMATED FROM NEWFOUNDLAND NEAR
4900N 5350W TO 4830N 4900W TO 5000N 4900W TO 6000N 5830W TO
6000N 4000W TO 3000N 5000W.
```

Outputs:

```
4900N 5350W
4830N 4900W
5000N 4900W
6000N 5830W
6000N 4000W
3000N 5000W
```

#### File Processing by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)

For a few examples of how to process files using Perl, I recommend checking out: [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

In your specific case, the following might be of use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'bulletin.txt';

open my $fh, "<", $file;

while (<$fh>) {
    print "$_\n" for /\b\d+[NS]\s+\d+[WE]\b/g;
}
```

Comment: Getting back to you comment.  The data is in a file called bulletin.txt.  what I want the program to do is read bulletin.txt then give me the output:                                        4900N 5350W
4830N 4900W
5000N 4900W
6000N 5830W
6000N 4000W
3000N5000W                                                          How do I do this with the regex?

Comment: Please look again - just trying to help out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I always appreciate the collaborative/wiki nature of SO.  Thank you for your assistance.